# BehaviorSubject not updating outside of websocket

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs

I have a WebSocketService that connects to a tornado server and sends a user name as well as a password. If these exist, the server responds with a boolean for the moment.

This boolean should be passed to the login component and if it is true, the user gets routed to the main page.

To share the data I am using a BehaviorSubject but the problem is, that it is not updating outside my websocket.subscribe method.

```
export class WebsocketService {

  ws : WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8085/ws");
  severMessage: Observable<boolean>[] =[];
  private messageSource =  new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  constructor(private _snackbar: MatSnackBar){
  }
  sendToServer(message: any){
    this.ws.subscribe(

     //prints true
      msg => {this.severMessage.push(msg.isUser);this.messageSource.next(!this.messageSource.value);console.log(this.messageSource.value)},
      err => console.log("Error " + err),
      () => console.log("Completed")
    );
    this.ws.next(message);

    //prints false
    console.log(this.messageSource.value);
    if(this.severMessage.length != 0){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


}
```

Any ideas on how I can successfully update the BevhaviourSubject so the value also changes outside if the subscribe?

Otherwise I am also open to new ideas on how to pass a message to the login component that the user exists.

Comment: It is successfully updated, just not yet when you log it. Message arrives later

Comment: That was it. I put a delay of 1 second in and the message updated successfully.
Thank you!